# S3 PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I had trouble uploading images locally to Python code and aws cli.

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

- My S3 is all public access unblocked.
- My S3 ACL is the default state enabled.
- My S3 Bucket Policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::myid:user/myuser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- My IAM user's policy includes S3 Full Access and also gave me access to my bucket.
- Of course, I created my user access key and registered it in aws configure.

I executed this command.

```bash
$ aws s3 cp 0.jpg s3://mybucket/0.jpg
$ aws s3 cp --acl public-read 0.jpg s3://mybucket/0.jpg
# upload failed: 0.jpg to s3://mybucket/0.jpg An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

And I executed this code.

```py
import os
from config import aws_config
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id=aws_config.ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=aws_config.ACCESS_PW,
                      region_name=aws_config.REGION
                      )

file_name = './0.jpg'
bucket = 'mybucket'
key = '0.jpg'

client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)

# boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload ./0.jpg to mybucket/0.jpg: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Please I want you to tell me how to solve it.

Comment: In the **Permissions** tab of the bucket, if you click **Edit Object Ownership**, is it set to "ACLs disabled (recommended)" or "ACLs enabled"?

Comment: Is it the same result if you use `client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)`?

Comment: Yes, I turned off the ACL and turned it on.

The Python function proceeded with the comment you left.
Not only did we use the `s3.upload_file` function, but we also used the `s3.put_object` function.

Comment: And I'm working on a bucket created by another federation user as a federation user. I turned on the ACL and tried typing my id, but the error was the same.

Comment: The key is missing from the text, but the function is filled in exactly the actual code.

Comment: Is MFA activated for your accout?

Comment: Yes, MFA is enabled. ￼

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.
The company security policy was set as follows.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "sts:GetSessionToken" // This Action
        ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
    "BoolIfExists": {
        "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
            }
        }
}
```

I got a token issued by local pc.

```bash
$ $ aws sts get-session-token --duration-seconds 129600 --serial-number <IAM_User_Identifier> --token-code <MFA_Code>
```

The following Credentials was issued and added to the ~/.aws/credentials file as follows.

```json
# Credentials

{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "AccessKeyId",
        "SecretAccessKey": "SecretAccessKey",
        "SessionToken": "SessionToken",
        "Expiration": "Expiration"
    }
}
```

```bash
# ~/.aws/credentials

[mfa]
aws_access_key_id = <AccessKeyId>
aws_secret_access_key = <SecretAccessKey>
aws_session_token = <SessionToken>
```

After that, I was able to use it normally.